# How to hide xaml ui element in debug

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I create a textbox in xaml to monitor a value. this is useful when developing but i would like to hide it when running in release compile. i know i can hide the texbox by setting visibility, but i would like to automate it.

thanks.

Comment: Would this help [Hiding UI elements according user role](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/188271.aspx/1)?

Comment: does the links works? tried but redirected to main forum site

Comment: The page must have been removed but if you do a google search for "Hiding UI elements according user role" you can view a cached version of the page or [msdn search](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-US/silverlight?query=Hiding%20UI%20elements&refinement=112&ac=8)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I´m not sure if you can do this directly in XAML by defining conditional compilation directives. But it works using the codebehind file.

First give your TextBox a name to access it in the codebehind file.

```
<TextBox x:Name="debugTextBox" />
```

and then add code to your codebehind (like the constructor)

```
#if DEBUG
  debugTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
#else
  debugTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; // or Collapsed
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a great article [here](http://www.removingalldoubt.com/post.aspx?id=df1ecd61-3c77-49ad-9491-00aa05fab2f1) that describes how to enable features by using an XML namespace definition.  In general, it's a very low-friction approach.

Comment: Ooh, that is a neat idea! Good link!